# SQL parsing twice

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have the following table

```
Create table TestScene(
string varchar(60))
insert into TestScene values ('t_Scene');
insert into TestScene values ('v_Scene');
```

On this table,I want to parse each `string` and I'm doing that,the problem is that it's doubling the last field and I don't know why.Do you see what I'm missing?

```
DECLARE @contor int
DECLARE @stringut varchar(50)
DECLARE cursorName CURSOR -- Declare cursor
FOR 
Select string  FROM TestScene
 Select @contor=count(*) from TestScene
OPEN cursorName -- open the cursor
print @contor
FETCH NEXT FROM cursorName INTO @stringut
  PRINT @stringut+' '  -- print the name

   WHILE @contor>0
        BEGIN
           FETCH NEXT FROM cursorName INTO @stringut
                declare @i int,@j int
                set @j=charindex(@stringut,'_')
                set @i=0

                While @j<>0
                    begin
                        declare @str varchar
                        set @str = SUBSTRING(@stringut,@i,@j-1-@i)
                        print @str+' '
                        set @i=@j
                        set @j=charindex(@stringut,'_')
                    end
           PRINT @stringut -- print the name
           set @contor=@contor-1
        END

CLOSE cursorName -- close the cursor
DEALLOCATE cursorName -- Deallocate the cursor
```

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "it's doubling the last field", but you loss first row.

Comment: @HamletHakobyan I'm getting the following output after executing that piece of code `t_Scene 
v_Scene
v_Scene`

Comment: What you want to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's becuase you have fetched value in cursor twice one before while loop and one within it. Write as:

```
DECLARE @contor int
DECLARE @stringut varchar(50)
DECLARE cursorName CURSOR -- Declare cursor
FOR 
Select string  FROM TestScene
 Select @contor=count(*) from TestScene
OPEN cursorName -- open the cursor
print @contor
--FETCH NEXT FROM cursorName INTO @stringut-- no need
  PRINT @stringut+' '  -- print the name

   WHILE @contor>0
        BEGIN
           FETCH NEXT FROM cursorName INTO @stringut
                declare @i int,@j int
                set @j=charindex(@stringut,'_')
                set @i=0

                While @j<>0
                    begin
                        declare @str varchar
                        set @str = SUBSTRING(@stringut,@i,@j-1-@i)
                        print @str+' '
                        set @i=@j
                        set @j=charindex(@stringut,'_')
                    end
           PRINT @stringut -- print the name
           set @contor=@contor-1          
        END

CLOSE cursorName -- close the cursor
DEALLOCATE cursorName -- Deallocate the cursor
```